# Error deleting a solution attached to a case

Tags: userrecordaccess, authorization

I´m unable to delete an FAQ (solution) that is linked to a case record:

[image]

Clicking on delete:
[image]

I´ve checked the Organization wide default for object "Solution" but according to the Salesforce documentation:

The organization-wide sharing default setting can’t be changed for some objects:
Solutions are always Public Read/Write.

My settings about solution object:
[image]

[image]

Do you know why i´m not able to do delete a solution attached to a case?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Comment: You're trying to figure out the CaseSolution object. Not the Solution object. I believe users need to have at least read/write access to the case the solution is tied to, or possibly even full access (read/write/transfer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i´m the owner of the record (case). I guess access on CaseSolution Object is controlled by case. Do you have some other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case layout is overridden with a Visualforce page.
In my VF page i´m just using the tag apex:detail to render the case page.

The Case solution related list behaviour is controlled by Salesforce.There isn´t something that a developer can fix.
After some discussion with the Salesforce support, we discovered that there is a bug related to apex:detail vf tag.

```
       Hello,
        would like to inform you that your issue has been marked as known issue and progress can be monitored at following link :


https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1z6AAC


        As a workaround you can disable the Validate CSRF Token on GET Requests.

        Please refer following link for more information :


    https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-can-I-allow-autosave-by-URL&language=en_US
```

Answer (score 5):

Public Read/Write doesn't imply Delete. Check your profile settings.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sol_del.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! still no luck. I´ve updated my question to include permissions for solution object.I want just to remove the solution reference on the case. Not the solution record.Thanks again

Comment: Do you have edit rights on the case ? - you may need to first disconnect the solution from the case.

Comment: I´m the owner of the record (case).I´m able to edit it but not to remove the solution on the case layout.

Comment: Offhand, is a trigger on Case or Solution causing this error?

Comment: I´ve just checked in Eclipse triggers on case,solution,CaseSolution reference. Nothing,no luck :(